# Creating a function that can assess a column and give an output in a new column

Tags: r, function, if-statement

This is my first question, so I will attempt to give as much detail as possible.

I am attempting to create a function in which I can produce a new column containing "1" or "0" as my output based on whether or not the original column had a date listed or it had no value. Below is a small example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
            Column 1      New Column
    Obs.1   4/23/2012          1
    Obs.2                      0
    Obs.3   1/23/2016          1
```

I am not sure on  how to go about doing this. I have attempted to use `tapply()` and `ifelse()` in conjunction, but have not had any workable code. This is sort of what I am going for:

```
    TextToNumb <- function(df$column){
    Ifelse(df$column > 0, 1, 0)
    return(df$newcolumn
    }
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tidyverse` is your friend.

```
library(tidyverse) ## This will call multiple packages including dplyr
library(magrittr) ## This makes assignment back to the original dataframe by %<>%
df <- data_frame(Date = c("4/23/2012", "", "1/23/2016"))
df %<>% dplyr::mutate(Bin = ifelse(Date != "", 1, 0))
```

You do not need to specify a separate function. If you wish to check for whether the column is of type `Date` as well, you can do the following with the `lubridate` package, also part of `tidyverse`:

```
library(lubridate)
df %<>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Bin = ifelse(!is.na(parse_date_time(Date, 'mdy')), 1, 0))
```

If it is sufficient to check that something is there, you can use the first code. If you are relatively new to R, you can start with reading [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/), which is a great book.

Comment: Thank you. I am somewhat familiar with the tidyverse, I have dplyr, lubridate, and ggplot2, but have not used magrittr. (I began with individual packages not realizing there was an entire set). I am relatively new to R, currently doing some data camp courses and the edX course for statistics and R.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Kim 's response, this might be more direct:

```
df <- data_frame(Date = c("4/23/2012", NA, "1/23/2016"))
df %<>% mutate(Bin = ifelse(is.na(Date), 0, 1))
```

Using the `""` as a condition might report incorrect results.  I would suggest using `is.na` instead since the sample data set has a row entry without a value, not `""`.

Comment: Is there a way to assign values based on the presence or absence of any value, not just a date? (e.g. a value of 345 receives a 1, whereas a blank still yields a 0)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach using base `R`, exploiting a behaviour that sometimes comes in handy.

```
df$is_date = as.numeric(!is.na(df$date))
```

We use the vectorized function `is.na` to test each element of the `date` column for empty values, which gives us a boolean/logical vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE`. After reversing these values with `!`, we can simply convert them to binary integers with `as.numeric` because, in `R`,  `TRUE` and `FALSE` are actually the same as 1 and 0:

```
TRUE == 1
[1] TRUE
FALSE == 0
[1] TRUE
```